# Force user to login in home page

Tags: login, customization

I have a custom login form working properly on my home view. Nice. But what I want is when user try to view some page, be redirected to my home view instead of wp-login. Im trying to do this way:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_login');

function redirect_to_login(){
 if(!is_user_logged_in()){
   wp_redirect(home_url()); exit;
 }
}
```

It's not working. Browser says it has too many redirects. What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`template_redirect` is called on every page load including the home page so your code will redirect the user to the homepage even when user is visiting the homepage

You could add another condition there, `is_home()` or `is_front_page()`, depending on the setting in admin, but i recommend a longer approach for better compatibility

a) Hook into `login_url` to change the url for login. This tells wordpress that login form is present on homepage & `wp-login.php` should not be used

```
add_filter('login_url', 'change_login_url');
function change_login_url() {
    return home_url('/');
}
```

b) Use `auth_redirect()` which makes sure user is redirected back to the previous page
c) Use `wp` hook and not `init` since the conditional is_front_page() will not work as $wp_query global has not been set yet.

```
add_action('wp', 'force_user_login');
function force_user_login() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in())
        auth_redirect();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another condition:

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() and ! is_home() ) {
    # redirect …
}
```